# What does the "Debian-10" mean in the response of the ssh server "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1" mean?

Tags: debian, openssh

When I use netcat to connect to an SSH port of a Debian system (`nc host 22`), I got the response `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1`. What does this `Debian-10` mean? The host is on Debian 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply reflects the Debian revision of the package currently in Debian 9; see the [package page](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/openssh) for details. The current version is 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u1; you can ignore the “1:”, then “7.4p1” is the version of [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.4), and “10+deb9u1” means this is the tenth release of the Debian package, updated for Debian 9 for the first time (more strictly, this is the first Debian 9 update following the tenth release of the Debian package of OpenSSH 7.4p1). The [Debian changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/o/openssh/stable_changelog) lists the changes made in the successive Debian packages of OpenSSH 7.4p1.

Put another way, “Debian-10+deb9u1” means it’s OpenSSH as packaged by Debian, and the Debian part of the version number (which is specific to the OpenSSH package) is “10+deb9u1”. The 10 there has nothing to do with the Debian release.